# perform the same showHide effect in multiple places on the page with different YT videos in every div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

The "show me" element, when clicked generates showHide effect. Iframe is loaded only after the webpage is rendered, which makes the website more efficient in terms of its size. However it works only with one div. Technically I could copy and paste the same function all over the place with different class names, but it'd make my code really sloppy and less efficient. What I'd like to accomplish:

- perform the same showHide effect in multiple places on the page with different YT videos in every div element
- still be able to load a content after page is rendered

HTML:

```
<div class="#">
   <a href="#" id="show_me"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i>
   <span>Show</span> Me</a>
   <div id="i_frame"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show_me").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).is(".opened") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("opened").find(".icon").removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down").parent().find("span").text("Show");
        $("#i_frame").hide().html("");

    } else {
        $(this).addClass("opened").find(".icon").removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-up").parent().find("span").text("Hide");
        $("#i_frame").show().html("<iframe width='100%' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/#' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    }

});
});
```

CSS:

```
#i_frame {
display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/fkcnncjm/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code more modular by using classes and DOM traversal to find the elements.

You could also data attributes to assign different videoes to each iframe etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show_me").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).toggleClass('opened')
               .find('.icon')
               .toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down')
               .end()
               .find('span')
               .text(function(_, txt) {
                   return txt === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
               });

        var iframeEl = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.i_frame');

        if (iframeEl.toggle().find('iframe').length === 0) {
            var iframe = $('<iframe />', {
                width           : '100%',
                height          : '315',
                src             : iframeEl.data('yt'),
                frameborder     : '0',
                allowfullscreen : 'true'
            }).appendTo(iframeEl)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.i_frame {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="show_me"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i><span>Show</span> Me</a>
    <div class="i_frame" data-yt="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="show_me"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i><span>Show</span> Me</a>
    <div class="i_frame" data-yt="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FrG4TEcSuRg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly. Thank you for you help and good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to fix your  JS.

A quick fix will be changing the line to

`$(this).siblings('#i_frame').toggle();`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/Lwbtnwhq/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really write the code now, if it's still not answered, i'll answer when i get home but basically what you want is:

1. Don't bind the function as `$("#show_me").click(function(e){` but rather define the named function itself in your script. (e.g. `function myFunction(button, e)`)
2. For every such div button add a `onClick="myFunction(this, e)"`
3. Use `button` to identify the 'frame' that it controls (one of the easier ways would be adding an attribute on the link, e.g. `<a controledFrame="i_frame" />`) and then getting it as `$(button).attr('controledFrame')` .

Answer (score 0):

This seems overall a cleaner solution. I tried to keep the functionality exactly the same, but I wouldn't remove the iframe every time, I would just keep them there and hide them once they're loaded. Anyway, here's my solution:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".show_me").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        var iframe_string = $(this).hasClass('opened') ? "<iframe width='100%' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/#' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>" : "";
        $(this).parent().find('.i_frame').html(iframe_string);
    });
});
```

```css
#i_frame {
    display: none;
}

.show_me:after {
  content: "Show me";
}

.show_me.opened:after {
  content: "Hide me";
}

.show_me.opened .icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single">
  <div class="#">
  <a href="#" class="show_me"><i class="icon fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <div class="i_frame"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I tested it with more iframes too and it worked, I left one in the example for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

---

If you add the YouTube 'src' as a data attribute onto the link you can store it as a variable and inject it into each iframe as required.

Have amended your fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/g5yku10s/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".show-vid").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var vidSrc = $(this).data('video');

    if ($(this).is(".opened") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("opened")
        .find(".icon")
        .removeClass("fa-angle-up")
        .addClass("fa-angle-down")
        .find("span")
        .text("Show");

        $("#i_frame").hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("opened")
        .find(".icon")
        .removeClass("fa-angle-down")
        .addClass("fa-angle-up")
        .find("span")
        .text("Hide");

        $("#i_frame iframe").attr('src', vidSrc);
        $("#i_frame").show();

    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `toggleClass()`, `.data()`, `next()`, selector next sibling `+` etc..

[<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/54hpaL3z/)

## SNIPPET

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
    var vID = Number($(this).data('vid'));
    var video = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ch5MEJk5ZCQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/o0u4M6vppCI', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/_lK4cX5xGiQ'];
    var ifrm = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + video[vID] + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass('on off').find(".fa").toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
    $(this).hasClass('on') ? $(this).next().html(ifrm) : $(this).next().html("");
  });
});
```

```css
.off + .frame {
  display: none
}
.on + .frame {
  display: block
}
.fa-angle-up + span:after {
  content: 'Hide'
}
.fa-angle-down + span:after {
  content: 'Show'
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vid">
  <a href="#/" class="btn off" data-vid='0'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i><span></span></a>
  <div class='frame'></div>
</div>

<div class="vid">
  <a href="#/" class="btn off" data-vid='1'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i><span></span></a>
  <div class='frame'></div>
</div>

<div class="vid">
  <a href="#/" class="btn off" data-vid='2'><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-down"></i><span></span></a>
  <div class='frame'></div>
</div>
```